# How to wrap a rule in Bazel?

Tags: bazel, bazel-rules

I use bazel configure_make rule to build 3rd party lib. This lib requires specifying paths to compiler in its configure options (or it uses default compiler, like /usr/bin/gcc, that is definitely wrong for cross-compilation).
I want to make my BUILD file free of configurable paths to toolchain, and I see, that I can get a toolchain from ctx in rule implementation. Idea is to get compiler/linker/etc paths from ctx and add them to configure options of configure_make rule, so the BUILD file will not have any info about toolchain.
I made a POC - copied original configure_make rule and changed its implementation - it works as I want. But I don't want to keep a copy of configure_make, if there is a way to write some wrapper for this rule.
Generally, what I want:

```
def _new_impl(ctx):
    find_cpp_toolchain(ctx)
    attrs = ctx.attr
    # add new configure options somehow
    # pass them to configure_make ???

new_rule = rule (
    # all configure_make attrs
    impl = _new_impl,
    ...
)
```

For now, after reading bazel docs it seems impossible, but I know, that I'm not an expert in bazel, so I could miss something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible in current version.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: "It is impossible" is an answer.

Comment: Yes, you can achieve the goal of this question by patching the existing rule, as I wrote in question about POC. But it is impossible with vanilla rule